# Not Equal Condition for RewriteRule on .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How to apply NOT EQUAL condition in inside RewriteRule statement.
For example, I want to call mypage.php file and pass an argument only when user not typed "test" data as a parameter. Other than "test" data system should call mypage.php by passing the given argument.

```
RewriteRule ^/?mypage/!(test)$ mypage.php?arg=$1 [L,NC]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use it like this :

```
RewriteRule ^/?mypage/((?!test).*)$ mypage.php?arg=$1 [L,NC]
```

((?!test).*) means Any characters zero or more times excluding **test** .